# NextJs custom Express Server not working properly

Tags: express, next.js

I recently decided to migrate to NextJs, but I'm having a few problems doing so. I have coded an ExpressJs API and now I want to use it as a Custom NextJs Server, as it says in the Docs, but I can't make it work

Here's my server.ts file (I'm using Typescript)

```js
///<reference path="../@types/index.d.ts"/>

import express from "express";
import next from "next";

// Rest of the imports (I removed to make the code shorter here)

import api from "./api";

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

require("dotenv").config();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    // All these following middlewares are imported previously
    server.use(logger("dev"));
    server.use(cors());
    server.use(compression());
    server.use(express.json());
    server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    server.use(cookieParser());
    server.use(NoCache);

    server.use("/api", auth.userHeader(), API); // My routes

    server.get("*", (req, res, next) => handle(req, res)); // NextJs Handle

    server.use(ErrorHandler);

    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Server Listening to port ${port}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });

export default app;
```

[Here's my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyssm.png)

I made a very simple app to test it (only a link to a login page)

When I run the project with `next` my application [works as expected and styles are applied][2], but obviously the ExpressJs API doesn't. However, when I run the `server.ts` file, the API works as expected (all endpoints are functional) and I get next's `compiled successfully` message, but [the page comes blank][3] given to a `style` applied by next automatically and also no CSS is loaded into the application (I added a style to the `body` tag on `globals.scss` to set the display of it to `block !important`, so it would overwrite the style that makes the page not show).

Here's my _app.tsx file

```js
import { AuthProvider } from "../context/auth";

import "../styles/globals.scss";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

and you can see I import the `globals.scss` right at the top

Here's my _document.tsx file

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class NextDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

export default NextDocument;
```

Here's my next.config.js file

```js
module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
  },
};
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I followed the documentation and a few videos I watched, but still no progress

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need any other information.

## UPDATE

After a few tests, I realized that when I remove typescript, everything works perfectly. I still don't know how to solve it and I don't want to lose all the benefits from typescript

My tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "pages/a.js", "pages/b.js", "pages/index.js", "server.js"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After more tests and realizing that typescript was the problem, I changed the target on my `tsconfig.json` from `ES5` to `ES6` and now everything works as expected.

Comment: Great! Thank you

Comment: Nice, this helped solve my issue as well :)

Comment: This worked for me. You saved me some hours!