# Next.js global css is not loading when getServerSideProps is used

Tags: css, next.js

I have global styles defined in my nextjs application inside `/styles/globals.css` and imported in `_app.tsx`

```
// import default style
import "../styles/globals.css";


function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 
   return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

and page in in `pages` directory (`pages/index.tsx`)

```
export async function getServerSideProps({req, res }) {
   // Some fetch here

   return {
      props: {
         someProps: objectFromFetchThere,
      },
   };
}

const Home: NextPage<{ someProps: SomeProps[] }> = ({ someProps }) => {
   return (
      <>
         <Head>
            <title>Home page</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
            <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
         </Head>
         <Layout>
            // More code here
         </Layout>
      </>
   );
};
```

When I'm running an application with `next dev` then everything is working fine (styles are loaded, getServerSideProps is called etc.), but when I'm running in production (`next build && NODE_ENV=production ts-node src/server.ts`) then global styles are not loaded (and `_app` file is also not used). Does it mean that I can't use global styles in pages with `getServerSideProps` exported? I didn't find anything related to that in NextJS documentation. Am I missing something here?

My custom server:

```
(async () => {
   try {
      const expressServer = express();
      await app.prepare();

      // Some custom routes defined over there like /facility - nothing that can overlap with styles.

      // Error middleware has to be used after other custom routes
      expressServer.use(
         (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
            console.error(err.stack);
            res.status(500).send("Unexpected error occurred.");
         }
      );

      expressServer.all("*", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
         try {
            await handle(req, res);
         } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error occurred handling", req.url, e);
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.end("internal server error");
         }
      });

      expressServer.listen(port, (err?: any) => {
         if (err) throw err;
         console.log(
            `> Ready on localhost:${port} - env ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`
         );
      });
   } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      process.exit(1);
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to the custom server and typescript used at the same time. Changing `"target": "es5"` to `"target": "es6"` fixed the issue. A solution is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/67520930/7932025.